# How to install the package ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Tags: package-management, fonts

I have the package installed. Now I want to use it to install the ms ttfonts, as stated in the description:

"This package allows for easy installation of the Microsoft True Type Core Fonts for the Web including: [list of fonts]"

so, how do I install the fonts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The packages comes with a post-install script (that is, literally a script that is executed after the package has been installed), which automatically downloads the fonts from Microsoft.

They should already be installed on your system, right after you have Accepted the end-user license agreement.

You can find the fonts in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/`. You *may* (I'm really not sure) need to refresh the font-cache so that applications can use them, or maybe the script has done that for you. The easiest way to make sure everything is up to date is to reboot your computer.

If the folder /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/ is empty try to use the command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and agree the license

Comment: How do you accept the end user license?  I can't click the "ok", I have tried enter and the space key with no luck.  I can page up and page down through the license agreement but unable to accept it.

Comment: The `OK` can be highlighted by pressing either the arrow keys or the `TAB` key. Once highlighted, press `Enter` key to press `OK`.

Comment: The "--reinstall" worked! You're a life saver... Thank you!

Comment: The `--reinstall` command fails in 18.10 with `Failed to fetch https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the fonts/final/andale32.exe  Redirection from https to 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mirrorproblem?failedmirror=netix.dl.sourceforge.net' is forbidden` what a pain: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1719863

Comment: Thanks! For some strange reason `dpkg-reconfigure` has no effect on this package.

Answer (score 19):

Just run the installer by:

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

To accept the license simply press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key until the 'O.k.' is highlighted and then <kbd>Return</kbd>.

In some cases the package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` fails to install properly with a message:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arial32.exe HttpError400
```

In this case after the install finished do the following:

Create a temporary directory and navigate into it:

```
TMP=$(mktemp -d)
cd "$TMP"
```

After that you can  use the following command to download all the fonts from their sourceforge location:

```
awk '/Url/ {system("wget "$2)}' /usr/share/package-data-downloads/ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Now run the updater to install them finally:

```
sudo /usr/lib/msttcorefonts/update-ms-fonts "$TMP"/*
```

All left to do now is to clear out the file telling the system that the install was incomplete.

```
sudo touch /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

And wrap up behind you, navigating out of the temporary directory and removing it:

```
cd ..
rm -r "$TMP"
```

In some cases you need to reboot to get the fonts recognized.

Tested and needed on Ubuntu 15.10, 16.04, 16.10, 17.04, 17.10 and 18.04!

Answer (score 2):

You can install in a noninteractive mode the packages via command line:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get install -y fontconfig    
RUN apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```