# Change mirror for ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Tags: apt, software-installation, fonts

Is it possible to change a mirror where ttf-mscorefonts-installer downloads fonts from? Currently, e.g. http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arial32.exe is blocked from my company office, but I can see that e.g. https://cfhcable.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the%20fonts/final/arial32.exe works.

Comment: @EliahKagan this answer is based on wget'ting those fonts from the same source - as I mentioned, this link is blocked from the office network, so how would wget work?

Comment: `wget` them from the other source instead. I've posted [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163770/22949) about how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the fonts from the mirror of your choosing, then run `update-ms-fonts` to use them. You won't want to download each one by hand, so you can use [the procedure in Videonauth's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/971058/22949) to [How to install the package ttf-mscorefonts-installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30043/how-to-install-the-package-ttf-mscorefonts-installer). Since that procedure, as written, would download the fonts with the `downloads.sourceforge.net` URLs you can't use, you'll have to change it to use the `cfhcable.dl.sourceforge.net` URLs. Here's a modified procedure:

1. Install `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` in the usual way. That is, run these commands and accept the license:

   ```bash
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
   ```

   You may see this stall, typically for less than half a minute:

   ```
   0% [Connecting to downloads.sourceforge.net (216.105.38.13)]
   ```

   And then an error that looks like this:

   ```
   Err:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
     Could not connect to downloads.sourceforge.net:80 (216.105.38.13), connection timed out
   E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe  Could not connect to downloads.sourceforge.net:80 (216.105.38.13), connection timed out
   E: Download Failed
   ```

   That's okay. At least currently, the installer doesn't continue to attempt to connect for subsequent files.
2. Make a temporary directory and `cd` to it. I prefer to just create a `tmp` subdirectory of my home directory and delete it when I'm done. If you script this, you're better off making the directory in the way Videonauth suggests.

   ```bash
   mkdir ~/tmp
   cd ~/tmp
   ```

   If that directory already exists, I suggest not using it, deleting its contents, or at least making sure it doesn't have any files in it whose names end in `.exe` before continuing.
3. Download the fonts, substituting the URLs you want to use. **This is the part that differs importantly from the procedure in [Videonauth's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/971058/22949).**

   ```bash
   awk '/Url/ {sub("downloads[.]sourceforge[.]net/corefonts","cfhcable.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the%20fonts/final",$2); system("wget "$2)}' /usr/share/package-data-downloads/ttf-mscorefonts-installer
   ```
4. Run `update-ms-fonts`. This only accepts absolute paths (so you can't write `*.exe` instead of `~/tmp/*.exe`). If your temporary directory isn't the `tmp` subdirectory of your home directory, adjust the command accordingly.

   ```bash
   sudo /usr/lib/msttcorefonts/update-ms-fonts ~/tmp/*.exe
   ```
5. Update the timestamp on the file APT uses to determine what installation steps still need to be completed:

   ```bash
   sudo touch /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/ttf-mscorefonts-installer
   ```

   You should be able to use the fonts now, and you shouldn't get any Software Updater dialog boxes about how files need to be downloaded.
6. Delete the temporary directory:

   ```bash
   cd
   rm -r tmp
   ```

> ***Credit goes to [Videonauth](https://askubuntu.com/users/522934/videonauth) for writing [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/971058/22949), from which this answer is derived.***